# Proving that a group is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If both $K$ and $G/K$ are finitely generated, show that $G$ is also finitely generated.

I know that if $K=\langle X \rangle$ then $X\subseteq K \subseteq  G$. But $G\ne \langle X \rangle$ unless $G=K$.

So in the case that $G\ne K$ I need to show that $G=\langle X' \rangle$. But I am not sure how I can start. Can someone provide any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G = \bigsqcup g_iK$ where the $g_i$ can be written in terms of finitely many generators $(h_1,\dots,h_k)$ since $G/K$ is finitely generated.  $K$ also has a finite list of generators $(k_1,\dots,k_s)$.  Then consider the list $(h_1,\dots,h_k,k_1,\dots,k_s)$ and show any element of $G$ can be written in these generators.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I do not see how $G = \bigsqcup g_iK$?

Comment: For any subgroup $H \leq G$ it's true that the left (or right) cosets form a partition of $G$.  To see this note that $g \in gH$ so the cosets cover G, and if $g \in xH \cap yH$ then $g=xh_1=yh_2 \Rightarrow x = yh_2h_1^{-1}=yh$ so that $xH=yH$